# SEVERE: Error filterStart error on Openshift Tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, openshift, spark-java

I have developed a small web service using [spark java](http://sparkjava.com/) I can start this service within eclipse and able to deploy in tomcat 7 using jdk 1.8.

works perfectly fine locally but when I deploy to openshift I am getting below error.

Any idea how do I fix this?

```
Jun 28, 2016 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal 
SEVERE: Error filterStart 
Jun 28, 2016 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal 
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors 
Jun 28, 2016 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR 
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/openshift/5756bfe82d52713d59000137/app-root/runtime/dependencies/jbossews/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 13,978 ms 
Jun 28, 2016 11:24:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time and debugging this problem I have found the issue.

1. Created a file logging.properties in \src\main\resources with following contents:

> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers =
>   java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

2. After deployment with above fix - exact error display that describe Open-Shift still using jdk1.7 . I did change some files in Open-Shift but platform always reset to jdk1.7

Due to some urgency I changed my java version to 1.7. I'll post again here when I'll fix with java 1.8

Comment: Looks in new version of OpenShift its not appearing